# Error while analyzing package during apk installation in app

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, apk

I want to have the abilities to update my app from my application, so I can download my apk file ( each of them are signed ). And when the installation want to start:
First of all: I have preparation of installation popup which appear
Then: another popup appear and told me "A problem occurred while parsing the package"
My error is like this:
[image: Image screenshot error]
So my app, didn't update. Could you help me please ?

I use Xamarin Forms but especially for Android.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.MyCompany.clamexdroid" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <application android:label="ClamexDroid" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
   </application>
   <queries>
      <intent>
          <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
      </intent>
   </queries>
</manifest>
```

My function when I click on my update Button

```
private async Task update()
    {
        this.popupIsVisible = false;
        this.IsBusy = true;

        string uri = "myLink.apk";

        HttpClient cli = new HttpClient();
        await cli.DownloadBasicFile(uri, DependencyService.Get<IDeviceDependency>().GetExternalAPKPath());
        DependencyService.Get<IDeviceDependency>().InstallApk();

        this.IsBusy = false;
    }
```

And my InstallApk() function ( I'm sure that the file is downloaded )

```
public void InstallApk()
    {
        Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ActionView).SetDataAndType(
            Android.Net.Uri.Parse($"content:///{this.GetExternalAPKPath()}"),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");

        promptInstall.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        promptInstall.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(promptInstall);
    }

public string GetExternalAPKPath()
    {
        try
        {
            return Path.Combine(Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath, "com.MyCompany.clamexdroid.apk");
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you can check the apk file you had downloaded has any damage. And then you can try to the following steps to install the apk:

1.Add the provider in the AndroidManifest.xml, such as:

```
 <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/androidicon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

2.Create the provider_paths.xml in the folder named xml below the values folder in the android part.

```
<paths >

<external-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

3.Use the following code to install the apk:

```
 var path = Path.Combine(Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath, "com.MyCompany.clamexdroid.apk");
        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);
        Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        Android.Net.Uri apkURI = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this, this.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".provider", file);
        install.SetDataAndType(apkURI, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        install.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
        StartActivity(install);
```

Comment: thanks, it's working! However, only work when I use signed apk but it's not a problem.